# Javascript - how to create nested json from list of dictionaries

Tags: javascript, json, list, nested

I am struggling to create a nested structure from a list of dictionaries/arrays.
I have data and I need to use it to build a JSON-ish object.

```
var data = [
   {"Customer":"C1", "Code":"0001","Sales Invoice":"SINV1","Amt":100, "Sales Person":"S1"},
   {"Customer":"C1", "Code":"0001","Sales Invoice":"SINV2","Amt":200, "Sales Person":"S1"}, 
   {"Customer":"C2", "Code":"0002","Sales Invoice":"SINV3","Amt":200, "Sales Person":"S1"}, 
   {"Customer":"C3", "Code":"0003","Sales Invoice":"SINV4","Amt":100, "Sales Person":"S2"},
   {"Customer":"C4", "Code":"0004","Sales Invoice":"SINV5","Amt":300, "Sales Person":"S2"}
];
```

Expected Output:

```
[{
    "Sales Person": "S1",
    "Data": [{
        "Customer": "C1",
        "Data": [{
            "Sales Invoice": "SINV1",
            "Amt": 100
          },
          {
            "Sales Invoice": "SINV2",
            "Amt": 200
          }
        ],
        "Code": "0001"
      },
      {
        "Customer": "C2",
        "Data": [{
          "Sales Invoice": "SINV3",
          "Amt": 200
        }],
        "Code": "0001"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Sales Person": "S2",
    "Data": [{
        "Customer": "C3",
        "Data": [{
          "Sales Invoice": "SINV4",
          "Amt": 100
        }],
        "Code": "0003"
      },
      {
        "Customer": "C4",
        "Data": [{
          "Sales Invoice": "SINV4",
          "Amt": 300
        }],
        "Code": "0004"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Appreciate your help in advance on this.

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to organise/summarise the data

And use `map` to format it.

```js
var data = [{"Customer":"C1", "Code":"0001","Sales Invoice":"SINV1","Amt":100, "Sales Person":"S1"},{"Customer":"C1", "Code":"0001","Sales Invoice":"SINV2","Amt":200, "Sales Person":"S1"}, {"Customer":"C2", "Code":"0002","Sales Invoice":"SINV3","Amt":200, "Sales Person":"S1"}, {"Customer":"C3", "Code":"0003","Sales Invoice":"SINV4","Amt":100, "Sales Person":"S2"},{"Customer":"C4", "Code":"0004","Sales Invoice":"SINV5","Amt":300, "Sales Person":"S2"}];
 
var newData = Object.values(data.reduce((c,v)=>{
  c[v["Sales Person"]] = c[v["Sales Person"]] || {"Sales Person" : v["Sales Person"], "Data" : {}};
  c[v["Sales Person"]]["Data"][ v["Code"] ] = c[v["Sales Person"]]["Data"][ v["Code"] ] || { Customer : v["Customer"],"Data": [], Code: v["Code"] }
  c[v["Sales Person"]]["Data"][ v["Code"] ].Data.push( {"Sales Invoice": v["Sales Invoice"],"Amt": v["Amt"]} );
  return c;
},{})).map(v=>{
  v.Data = Object.values( v.Data );
  return v;
});
      
console.log( newData );
```

Comment: Thank you Eddie for providing perfect solution. Highly appreciate your help.

Comment: Happy to help @SanjayKumar

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` with `Object.values()`. First group the data based on the `Sales Person` and then group it using `Customer` value. Then using `array#forEach` extract all `Customer` values in `Data`.

```js
var data = [{"Customer":"C1", "Code":"0001","Sales Invoice":"SINV1","Amt":100, "Sales Person":"S1"},{"Customer":"C1", "Code":"0001","Sales Invoice":"SINV2","Amt":200, "Sales Person":"S1"},{"Customer":"C2", "Code":"0002","Sales Invoice":"SINV3","Amt":200, "Sales Person":"S1"},{"Customer":"C3", "Code":"0003","Sales Invoice":"SINV4","Amt":100, "Sales Person":"S2"},{"Customer":"C4", "Code":"0004","Sales Invoice":"SINV5","Amt":300, "Sales Person":"S2"}];
var result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,o) => {
  r[o['Sales Person']] = r[o['Sales Person']] || {'Sales Person' : o['Sales Person'], Data : {} };
  r[o['Sales Person']].Data[o.Customer] = r[o['Sales Person']].Data[o.Customer] || {Data: [], Code: o.Code}
  r[o['Sales Person']].Data[o.Customer].Data.push({'Sales Invoice': o['Sales Invoice'], Amt : o['Amt']});
  return r;
},{}));

result.forEach(o => {
  o.Data = Object.values(o.Data);
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you  Hassan for your providing solution. Appreciate it.